# Как правильно пишется - в цвете или в цветах?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, прилагательные, окончания, множественное-число

В синем, бежевом и белом цвете или цветах?

Answer (score 3):

Выбираем вариант: **В синем, бежевом и белом цвете.**

Сравнить: в синем цвете, в бежевом цвете и в белом цвете.

Пример: Бежевый и белый цвет в интерьере.

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Имя существительное, которому предшествует два или несколько определений, указывающих на разновидности предметов, ставится **в форме единственного числа:**

4) если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений **внутренне связаны**, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в правой и левой руке, оперное и балетное искусство; Город был открыт для ветров с северной и восточной стороны.

**Внутренняя связь** в приведенном примере: прилагательные обозначают  разновидности цвета.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что здесь выбор правильного варианта зависит от контекста или от мысли, которую хочет выразить автор. Например, если речь идёт об интерьере, отдельные элементы которого имеют разные цвета, и при этом автор подчёркивает наличие этих трёх разных цветов, тогда нужно выбрать множественное число:

**В синем, бежевом и белом цветах.**

Этот вариант соответствует п.2.1. [по той же ссылке](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04).

Если же автор говорит, например, о характерной расцветке, содержащей перечисленные оттенки, тогда следует выбрать единственное число, как было указано в ответе **Jasmin**.

В литературе можно встретить множество примеров одного и другого типа. Приведу для примера две цитаты:

> В женских чулках после зачина идет широкая узорная полоса, выполненная
>   **в черном и белом цветах**. (Я. Н. Безносиков, ‎Анатолий Микушев, "Этнография и фольклор Коми", 1972.)
>
> Внимание автора поэтому может быть полностью направлено на проблемы
>   современных взаимоотношений людей в деревне, их психологию во всей
>   сложности — ее не изобразишь лишь **в черном и белом цвете**... (журнал "Иностранная литература", 1976.)